# Is there a better way to do this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering what the most effective way to do this MySQL statement that looks like the following

```
SELECT id FROM something WHERE x IN 
(58, 285, 287, 1928, 175, 1928, 2, 481, 2851, 2875, 21, 498, 582, 198, 18) 
AND y IN (57, 28, 29, 85, 101, 587, 201, 598, 982, 105, 78, 92, 100, 200, 909, 
1120, 592, 109, 581, 2752, 581, 201, 510 700);
```

There is a composite index on [x, y]

Seems like there's a more effective way to do this, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Could the `NOT IN` numbers for `x` and `y` possibly be shorter lists?

Comment: You could create separate tables to store the x and y values, index them, and then join to the `something` table, if that would make sense from a business logic point of view.

Comment: You could add x+y and store all possible sums in a list   select where x+y in [all sums] ?

Comment: As @TimBiegeleisen suggested, you could have some tables for look-up purposes. Is that viable for you?

Comment: A WHERE clause defining the upper and lower limits on both x and y might help - and I can't imagine there's much merit in including the same value more than once.

Comment: @ElDude I think that won't work. Look at the first x (58) and the first y (57). The sum is 115. Now suppose the table has a record with x=59 and y=56; then the sum is also 115, and the record would be selected with your method. But this would be wrong.

Comment: @space_food_ Are those numbers always the same, or are they different for each query?

Comment: The numbers change yes, and can be 100 different values in each set

Comment: @binarus I thought the operation might be surjective because the `IN` operation technically returns a Bool only. Hence, by adding `x` & `y` one could compress two list searches to one..?

Comment: @ElDude Not really. The example I gave in my first comment regarding this is simple: The sum of `58` (first member of the first `IN` list) and `57` (first member of the second `IN` list) is `115`. Thus, according to your method (unless I have misunderstood something), every row should be selected where `(x+y) = 115`. Now suppose the table has a row with `x=56` and `y=59`. The sum is `115`, so your method would select that row. But that clearly would be wrong since `56`is NOT in the `IN` list for `x` and `59` is NOT in the `IN` list for y. QED ...

Comment: @binarus - Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

Using IN() with 100 integers in each list isn't too much to ask of a query particularly if x & y are appropriately indexed. Any advantage in persisting those lists to tables may not be worth the effort unless they were stable or infrequently changed (and that different users don't need lists unique to each causing concurrency issues).

One thing to be aware of that those 2 independent lists are not evaluated as tuples as the following attempts to demonstrate:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cde10b/5)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE something 
    (`x` int, `y` int)
;

INSERT INTO something 
    (`x`, `y`)
VALUES
    (58, 57),
    (58, 28),
    (58, 29),
    (58, 30),
    (58, 31)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM `something` 
WHERE x IN (58) 
AND y IN (57, 28, 29)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cde10b/5/0)**:

```
|  x |  y |
|----|----|
| 58 | 57 |
| 58 | 28 |
| 58 | 29 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT *
FROM `something` 
WHERE (x,y) IN ((58,28),(58,29))
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cde10b/5/1)**:

```
|  x |  y |
|----|----|
| 58 | 28 |
| 58 | 29 |
```

Perhaps not the best of examples but hopefully useful.